# Display the lines that EITHER begin with hello OR end with hello (using egrep)

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I am trying to solve for the following and cannot seem to figure it out -- Display the lines that begin with hello OR end with hello (using egrep).

I have tried:

```
egrep '^hello|hello$' <filename>
```

Comment: What is the issue with this command ?

Comment: This looks correct. I just tried on a linux server. Using `egrep` on a test file, line `hello there` is shown, `say hello` is shown, `this hello there` is not shown. Make sure egrep is an actual egrep, not not a grep.

Comment: I think you have leading / trailing whitespace, use `egrep '^[[:space:]]*hello|hello[[:space:]]*$' <filename>`

Comment: I am trying to pull one or the the other, but I don't want it to pull lines that start with hello and end with hello. The problem is, the command also pulls lines that start and end with hello rather than lines that either start with hello OR end with hello. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need an AND with NOT condition to match the string. I don't know how to use this in regex. I found a same question, maybe it can help you.
https://superuser.com/questions/477463/is-it-possible-to-use-not-in-a-regular-expression-in-textmate

Answer (score 1):

To exclude the cases with **hello** at the start AND **hello** at the end use this pipe:

```
egrep '^hello|hello$' <filename> | egrep -v '^hello.*hello$
```

the -v option selects lines that don't match